# Question about 〜に〜てもらう

Tags: grammar

I came across both of these sentences:

> 1. 我々も、できるだけ早く問題を解決してキミに協力させてもらうよ
> 2. 王子様に喜んでもらえて嬉しさ満開です
>    <sup>(Character is a flower-human creature)</sup>

I know that てもらう refers to someone receiving a benefit/pleasure from an action.
I believe that in both of these sentences, the speaker is receiving the benefit, but I'm not positive as I'm a little confused by the に.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these two sentence, the two に modify different parts of the sentences.

> キミに協力させてもらうよ。
> It's my pleasure to help you. / Allow me to help you.

This is technically ambiguous, but キミに almost certainly modifies 協力する, not もらう. The subject of 協力する is the speaker himself. ～に協力する is a basic usage of the verb 協力する.

> 王子様に喜んでもらえて嬉しさ満開です。
> Prince, I'm blooming with joy that you're pleased!

This is also technically ambiguous, but in 90% of the time, 王子様に modifies もらえる. The subject of 喜ぶ is the prince. Another interpretation is "I'm happy that you're pleased about the prince", but it's unlikely.

And a sentence like this can be completely ambiguous.

> 彼に手紙を渡してもらいます。
>
> - I'll ask him to pass the letter (to someone else).
>   <sub>(The subject of 渡す is 彼.)</sub>
> - I ask (you) to pass the letter to him.
>   <sub>(The subject of 渡す is "you".)</sub>